# On using "confirm('message')" in JavaScript, making the browser navigation buttons disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, browser

I have a situation where in, when the user clicks the "back" button, I have to prompt for a "confirm" on a page using JavaScript. The result would decide whether to stay on the page or not.

I have used, the following:

```
   window.onbeforeunload = function () {

         var answer = return confirm("Please note by clicking the back button will reset your selection")

         if (!answer) {
            event.preventDefault();
         }
         else{

         // do something
         }
 };
```

Now, even if this prompts a popup on the page, the back button can still be clicked taking the user to the previous page.

On the other hand, by using the following.

```
   window.onbeforeunload = () => {return '';}
```

I get the message "Changes you made may not be saved.", with the prevention of "back", "forward", "refresh" and all such buttons on the page.

I want this same thing (the prevention of these buttons), to happen on "confirm('message')".

Answer (score 0):

```
function Confirm_something() {
    history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
      window.onpopstate = function () {
        history.go(1);
      };
    return confirm("Text you want?");
}

if(Confirm_something){
   console.log('user say yes'); //then call your save edit or delete functions.
}
else{
   console.log('user say no');
}
```

Comment: still, when there is a confirm prompt, I am able to click the back button.

Comment: I made changes, try now.

Comment: nope, the back button is accessible yet again. And, the confirm prompt, isn't popping up after I made the necessary changes.

Comment: the confirm prompt, isn't popping up after I made the necessary changes. Also, if we continuously click it multiple times, it goes back.

Comment: any solution reagrding this?